Reason for mosquitto_pub TLS error: alert unknown ca?
I am using a self signed certificate for Mosquitto MQTT broker.
When I try to publish something to the server via mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.sustainable-data-platform.org -p 8883 --cafile ./intermediate-mq.cert.pem -t test -m "fff aaa" -u <user> -P <pssw>
I am getting the following OpenSSL errors:
06-27T17:12:03: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14094413:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert unsupported certificate
06-27T17:12:03: OpenSSL Error[1]: error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl handshake failure
06-27T17:13:30: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca

For verifying the CA file:
$ sudo openssl x509 -noout -text -in ./intermediate-mq.cert.pem
[sudo] password for malte: 
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 4097 (0x1001)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = DE, ST = NRW, L = Koeln, O = sustainable data platform, OU = tools, CN = mqtt.sustainable-data-platform.org, emailAddress = <mail>
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 27 13:42:33 2024 GMT
            Not After : Jun 10 13:42:33 2035 GMT
        Subject: C = DE, ST = NRW, O = sustainable data platform, OU = tools, CN = mqtt.sustainable-data-platform.org, emailAddress = <mail>
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                E3:1C:A7:6A:FB:20:CE:A8:6C:BF:37:36:D2:C3:19:5B:D0:AF:DB:AB
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:74:14:B3:65:28:6E:F5:27:C5:82:09:67:0A:9D:F8:AD:4D:75:FB:4B

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         ...

Part of mosquitto.conf:
listener 8883

#certfile
# using self signed stuff
keyfile /etc/pki/CA/intermediate/private/mqtt.sustainable-data-platform.org.key.pem
cafile /etc/pki/CA/intermediate/certs/intermediate-mq.cert.pem
certfile /etc/pki/CA/intermediate/certs/mqtt.sdp.cert.pem

How can I debug this or what do I need to check here?
More specific: what does alert unknown ca mean here?
Do I need to use the --insecure flag, like suggested here, because it is a self signed certificate (teaser: this did not help)?

Given the name, does the intermediate-mq.cert.pem have both the intermediate and root certificate?

@hardillb just intermediate. I can create a chain, but do I then need to put this into mosquitto.conf (cafile /etc/pki/CA/intermediate/certs/chain.cert.pem) - like I guess?

@hardillb One more thing: when I put the root certificate into the chain, could the handshake fail, if the root key has a password?

yes, mosquitto will not prompt for the password to unlock the key

@hardillb I did this, the TLS error has changed into :sslv3 alert unsupported certificate. Is it related to the password in the root key? - I will try one (and a whole new chain) without password.

@hardillb Mhm, it gives error:14094413: ... alert unsupported certificate without password in keys, too. But mosquitto (v1.6.10) does support self signed certificates?
